# pip error while installing package in Cygwin/Python2.7

Tags: python, cygwin

I installed Python2.7.3 in Cygwin using [this guide](https://superuser.com/a/443094/372910), I then installed pip from source.

When I try to use pip:

```
$ pip install sqlalchemy
Downloading/unpacking sqlalchemy
Downloading SQLAlchemy-0.7.8.tar.gz (2.6Mb): 2.6Mb downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package sqlalchemy
  137 [main] python2.7 1060 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'itertools.dll' (0x2C0000) is already occupied
  Error [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable while executing command python setup.py egg_info
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
  status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 245, in run
  requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1009, in prepare_files
  req_to_install.run_egg_info()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 225, in run_egg_info
  command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 221, in call_subprocess
  cwd=cwd, env=env)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1143, in _execute_child
  self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

Storing complete log in /home/joshfriend/.pip/pip.log
```

Found a guide noting that this happens, and said that running `rebaseall` should fix this. I tried, and it didn't. I would assume that this is because I did not install python2.7 with the cygwin installer and therefore was not affected by the `rebaseall`.

**UPDATE:**

I gave the wrong link to the instructions I used to install python (sorry). I went back and fixed my explanation of what I did...

Comment: looks like pip was down or you are running another python pip install

Comment: Why are you using cygwin anyway ?

Comment: This was the only instance of pip running at the time. As a Mac user, I greatly prefer a unix like environment when I have to work with windows.

Comment: @KienTruong Because it's the least terrible way to emulate a Unix system on Windows, yes even in these days of WSL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't just "run `rebaseall`" the way the site you link to implies. You need to do the following:

1. Exit all running Cygwin programs. Yes, all of them, even your shell, even MinTTY, even X11.
2. Start > Run > `C:\cygwin\bin\ash.exe` > OK.
3. `cd /bin`
4. Type `./rebaseall` and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.
5. That may take a few minutes. Go get a coffee.
6. Come back, try again.

I've no idea how `apt-cyg` works, but it appears to use the standard Cygwin repositories. Unless you have very good reason to do otherwise, I'd use the standard Cygwin `setup.exe` installer for all your install/upgrade/whatever needs, as it does a pretty good job of doing all your rebasing for you.

In particular, if the above steps don't work, I'd uninstall Python with `apt-cyg`, and try again by installing it with the standard installer. You can download it again from [cygwin.com](http://www.cygwin.com/) if you need to.

Comment: I had done that before, and just tried again with no luck. also, I had previously put in the wrong link to the guide I used to install python in Cygwin, which I have now updated.

Answer (score 3):

Try simply running export temp=  from the cygwin console. It solved the issue for me.

Comment: That is bonkers. Works. Windows is so dumb. Cheers.